# How to populate select2 with custom input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I implemented a `select2` dropdown that allows the user to enter a custom input...

```
$("#select").select2({
  createSearchChoice:function(term, data) {
    if ($(data).filter(function() {
      return this.text.localeCompare(term)===0;
    }).length===0)
    {return {id:term, text:term};}
  },
  multiple: false,
  selectOnBlur: true,
  data: [{id: 1, text: '1'}, {id: 2, text: '2'}, {id: 3, text: '3'}]
});
```

This works fine, but there is a scenario where I need to programatically set a custom value for the `select2` dropdown. I tried doing the following...

```
// Doesn't work
$('#select').val('val', custom);

// Doesn't work
$('#select').val(custom);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nd9zbg3e/) of my select dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to accomplish what I want. The solution was...

```
$('#select').select2('data', {id: id, text: custom});
```

The following will set the input as whatever value `custom` is without adding to the list itself.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ro9u8f3e/).

Comment: If you want to add the new option to the list, i don't there is any other option than to `destroy()` the existing select2 and creating a new one with a different dataset.

Comment: @lofihelsinki makes sense, for my particular use case, luckily I don't need to add it to the list, but good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to show selected value? if so you can add

```
$('#select').val(custom).attr("selected", "selected").change();
```

Comment: For some reason there is still no change

Comment: made some change, Can you try it again! Thanks @Bolboa

Comment: Still nothing, not sure why. Were you able to get it working in a fiddle?  I provided one above.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you need to trigger the change for select2 to take effect.

```
$('#select').val(custom).change();
```

Comment: It's not working for me, are you able to get it working in a fiddle? I provided a link above

Comment: It does work. You just need to make sure you are passing 0, 1, or 2 into the `val()`, as per your fiddle example.

Comment: If I do that, I will get an existing value in the list, not a custom input that I want to set.

Comment: Then this may help: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items